# scrollHeight set to 0 even though console.dir shows a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS and am having difficulty with something that seems obvious.  I want to reset the height of a textarea to fit the pre-populated content within it.  For some reason it always sets to either 0 or 12 px.  In trying to debug I boiled down the issue to the following :

```
var scrollElement=jQuery(".comp-info textarea")[0];
console.dir(scrollElement);
    
var scrollElementHeight=scrollElement.scrollHeight;
console.log(scrollElementHeight);
```

After running this, in the console I see that within the console.dir collection(?) scrollHeight is 250 but the console.log(scrollElementHeight) shows 0.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Many thanks

Comment: If I understand that correctly, when you run console.dir, you are not printing the current values of that object but the reference to that object, when you expand the content you se the current values instead of the values present when you did run that console.dir method. I'm not sure what's the rest of the code, but you may need to wait a bit before getting the height (hard to suggest something without context)

Comment: Hi Arieljuod, Many thanks that fixed my problem and helped my understanding greatly! Im not quite sure how to close this question off now.